# How can I accurately and properly update records to maintain archival integrity with high concurrency?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Provider]
(
    [Id] BIGINT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    [Description] CHARACTER VARYING(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL,
    [DeletedOn] DATETIMEOFFSET NULL,

    UNIQUE([Name], [DeletedOn]),

    CHECK([DeletedOn] IS NULL OR ([CreatedOn] <= [DeletedOn])),

    PRIMARY KEY([Id])
);
```

All access to `Provider` is controlled with stored procedures. All stored procedures are required to follow a "fail fast" policy, where parameters are first validated and then operations are executed.

A `Provider` record may be created, updated, and deleted (soft).

Creation is standard and is only wrapped in a stored procedure to maintain consistency and for argument validation.

Deletion (soft) simply updates the `DeletedOn` column of a record specified by its `Id` column.

Updates are where things get tricky and is also what my question is focused on. In order to maintain a history of changes applied to a specific `Provider`, we use multiple records. `Id` identifies a specific instance of a `Provider` entity. A series of changes are done against a particular `Provider` entity and each `Provider` entity is uniquely identified by its `Name`. The latest effective `Provider` entity version is identified by `(Name, DeletedOn)` where `DeletedOn IS NULL` is satisfied.

To enforce this model above, we ensure with a `UNIQUE` constraint that no two `Provider` records may be considered the latest. With stored procedures, the logic surrounding deleting (soft) the old record and inserting the new record is controlled in a transaction. Currently, we use `SET TRANSACTION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` to ensure that no new records are inserted between statements, that would cause the current transaction to fail due to phantom records being present during constraint checking.

The problem is that this destroys concurrency. Full table locks are taken pretty often and this table has tons of reads but not so many inserts or updates. It seems that SQL Server is locking on `Name` and then escalating to a table lock to prevent  any new records from being inserted, as would be expected from the `SERIALZABLE` transaction level.

This seems like a good candidate for more granular optimization.

What hints or other changes could I make to this table to ensure that the above requirements are still met and that would allow conflicting inserts to block each other but allow obviously non-conflicting actions to be taken?

Comment: Why are you deleting the old record and inserting a the new record in a transaction.  How is that not just a simple update.  If name and deleted on is unique then why a separate PK?  Why is there not FK on name>

Comment: @Blam Using `PRIMARY KEY(Name, DeletedOn)` would prevent `Provider` from being referenced by a foreign key. Placing `Name` into its own table and simply replacing it with a `BIGINT` foreign key reference into the `Provider` table would not solve any issues as far as I can tell; what is your reasoning on this one? The old record is being deleted and a new record is being inserted in order to track change history, as mentioned in the question. A transaction is being used currently for the `SERIALIZABLE` transaction level, to prevent phantom records from being an issue when it comes to committing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a history table independent of the main table. To accomplish the need for atomicity, I simply wrapped the update on the live table and the insert into the history table in a repeatable read transaction.